# I cant open ports on my router. im connected to internet via two routers

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

First of all, sorry if I make some mistakes with my english, it is not my first language.

My first router(The main router) model is a Technicolor CGA2121 and the second one is a DIR-615( directly connected to my computer).

I've followed a guide i saw on youtube, basically, i've

1. set up static ip addresses for both my PC and my second router, also,
2. made a port forwarding from my second router to my pc
3. asked my ISP to open the port from my first router to my second router.(Since they wont let me access to my router by myself)

Also my firewalls are all turn off, the port in particular i'm trying to open is 25565.
But when i test it on https://canyouseeme.org i get an error, i've tried in multiple services like Emule, to check if the port is unreachable and it seems that it is.

Now i'm not sure where the error could be, since my second router doesn't have a direct "Port forwarding " option, and since i cant access my first router i cannot check if theres something wrong in the configuration, so i was wondering.

Maybe im missing something very obvious?
Is there a way to check where the problema migth be ( in my first or second forwarding )
also, i saw another trheat about a router wich is similar to mine, and didn't have the port forwarding option either,

[I don't see a port forwarding option in my router, how can I set up a ssh server then?](https://superuser.com/questions/1144059/i-dont-see-a-port-forwarding-option-in-my-router-how-can-i-set-up-a-ssh-server)

however the solution he proposses is to get the correct username and password, wich i dont understand. the username and password im using does not grant me full access to my router?

Thanks in advance, any help would be gratly apreciated.
Also if more info is needed just comment it and i will try to edit that in as soon as possible.

Comment: What is the second router used for? Do you actually need a separate network behind the second router? “Double NAT” (as seems to be your case) is sometimes tricky to get to work. *If possible*, try to simplify the situation by creating a single subnet (i.e. do not use the second router to “route” but just use it as a switch).

Comment: The only reason ther'es a second router is because we have multiple devices conected to it, that being the case, is there a way to configure the second router to act just like a switch  ?

Comment: Just plug everything (including the uplink to the main router) into the 4 LAN ports and nothing into the WAN port. Your router will basically be a switch from then on.

Comment: Will it be able to provide wirelles acces if i do so?, i mean Wifi

Comment: Yes. If it’s working now, you probably don’t have to change anything in the configuration of your router. Make sure you change the LAN IP address of your second router to an address within your main network and disable DHCP on it.

Comment: Thanks in advanced i pluged everything as you said, but now im unable to access my second router, even tough i'm putting its new ip adress on my web browser, this ip changed automatically. when i reset the router. and now it is in my main network. Maybe i should've done everything manually ? when i tried o change the ip adress , it looked like every ip adress from my main network was alerady taken. thats why i decided to reset my second router